# Hadoop task schedulers: Capacity vs Fair sharing or something else?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-plugins, scheduled-tasks

### Background

My employer is progressively shifting our resource intensive ETL and backend processing logic from MySQL to Hadoop ( dfs & hive ).  At the moment everything is still somewhat small and manageable ( 20 TB over 10 nodes ) but we intend to progressively increase the cluster size.

Now that hadoop is being shifted into production use, its becoming a bigger issue of batch scheduling and sharing the cluster between ad-hoc user hive queries, hourly M/R processes, and I believe eventually some usage of hbase.  The fear is that a naive query will be made by a user that could potentially run for an unreasonable amount of time ( say 4 hours ) clogging up the task queue and producing potential infrastructure load instabilities.

### Question

Another section of my company has already been burned by Flume's immaturity, so my question is, how stable are the two known schedulers ( Capacity & Fair ) and besides usage in their sponsoring companies ( Yahoo & Facebook ) are they used elsewhere?

### Edit:  Background info

http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2008/11/job-scheduling-in-hadoop/

http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/fair_scheduler.html

http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/capacity_scheduler.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ship CDH with the Fair Share scheduler on by default. It's quite stable.

Comment: took me a minute to figure out who you are :)